# JavaScript data structure explanation

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Given the following JavaScript data structure - how would you describe it?

```
BLA = {
  date : 12345678,
  layers : {
    bottom : "bottomLayer"
  },
  numbers : [5,4,2,2,4],
  start : function(){}
}
```

I would say the following about above data structure, do you agree?

> It is an object literal called `BLA`. `BLA` is initializted with 4 object members. The first one is `date` which value is `12345678` and the second one is the member `layers` which recursively stores an literal itself: `bottom:"bottomLayer"`. The third member is referenced as `numbers` which holds an array with 5 values. The last member is referenced as `start` and its respective value is an anomyous function.

Comment: Is this a real question, or homework??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right on track, except for this part which reads a little awkwardly:

> second one is the member “layers” which recursively stores an literal itself: 'bottom:”bottomLayer”'

Instead I would just describe it as an object literal itself:

> second one is the member “layers” which is an object literal containing the string property: 'bottom' whose value is ”bottomLayer”

`layers` is not really doing anything recursive; that's not quite the appropriate term. But you clearly understand what the object is.